# I need to be able to count by hour the first iteration of each unique story

Tags: google-sheets, unique, counting

I get data from our CMS that shows all actions of staff within that system.
My challenge is to be able to show in a chart only the first iteration of each story as published and the hour in which it occurred.
A single story can be published multiple times during a day.
Using countuniquesif I can get the number of unique stories per hour by using:

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(Sheet0!I2:I60000,Sheet0!G2:G60000,"NL_Stories/Ready",Sheet0!E2:E60000,"Webpub",Sheet0!B2:B60000,"08") 

=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(Sheet0!I2:I60000,Sheet0!G2:G60000,"NL_Stories/Ready",Sheet0!E2:E60000,"Webpub",Sheet0!B2:B60000,"09")

Etc
```

However, if that story is published in the period from 8am-9am (08 in column B), if it is published again between 9am-10am (09 in column B) it will be counted again.
How can I limit this to just the first time it is published and excluded in any of the other hours.
I have attached a spreadsheet with two tabs, one with the raw data and two with what I currently do.

Any assistance appreciated

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V-kZyUUfXtaf6pMYDCxNSUjjWclOrUcW2Pk2y678RZo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you point out example of bad & correct count from within your shared sheet?

Comment: There is a second TAB called Stories by Hour. That is a correct count based on countuniquesif, but as I said some stories are counted again if they are in a different hour.